# Dual space of $\mathcal{P}(M)$, when regarded as an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, filters

This question stems from the well-known observation that the power set $\mathcal{P}(M)$ of any set $M$ can be given an  $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space structure by the symmetric difference operation.
Any powerset is then naturally a dual space, namely of the subspace of the finite-element subsets, as can be seen from the pairing
$$
\mathcal{P}(M)\times \mathcal{P}^{\mathrm{fin}}(M) \to \mathbb{F}_2, (A,B)\mapsto |A\cap B| \mod 2
$$

The question now is: Can we find a similarly explicit description for $\mathcal{P}(M)^*$? More ambitiously: Does the following construction encompass the whole space?

For any ultrafilter $U$ on $M$, we obtain an element in this space via "integration against $U$", i.e. as the map
$$\phi_{U}:\mathcal{P}(M) \to \mathbb{F}_2, A \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $A\in U$ and} \newline
0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

It is not difficult to show that the $\phi_U$ are linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}(M)^*$: For different ultrafilters $U_1,...,U_n$, we may always find subsets $A_1,...,A_{n-1}$ of $M$ such that $A_i\in U_n $ but $A_i\notin U_i$ for each $i$. Then the intersection $A_1\cap...\cap A_{n-1}$ still lies in $U_n$ but in no other $U_i$ - consequently $\phi_{U_n}$ is not a linear combination of the other $\phi_{U_i}$.

Since $M$ supports $2^{2^{|M|}}$ different ultrafilters (assuming AC), the space spanned by the $\phi_U$ at least has the correct dimension (again assuming AC). (Note also that it contains the image of $\mathcal{P}^{\mathrm{fin}}(M)$ under the double dual embedding: Every element gets identified with the principal ultrafilter generated by its singleton.)

I have no clue how to show that these maps generate the whole space though. Do you know an argument? Alternatively, can you give a description of a functional that is not of this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any partition of $M$ into subsets $A_i$ (say, the singletons).  Note that the $A_i$ are linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}(M)$, so any collection of them can be sent to $1$ by a functional on $\mathcal{P}(M)$.  However, any $\phi_U$ takes the value $1$ on at most one $A_i$, and so any linear combination of $\phi_U$'s takes the value $1$ on at most finitely many of the $A_i$.  So no functional which sends infinitely many $A_i$ to $1$ can be in the span of the $\phi_U$.  (So "explicitly", for instance, if $M$ is infinite then any functional that sends every singleton to $1$ cannot be in the span of the $\phi_U$, though good luck actually writing down such a functional explicitly.)

Interestingly, though, this is actually the only obstruction.  That is, the span of the $\phi_U$ is exactly the set of functionals $f$ on $\mathcal{P}(M)$ such that for any partition of $M$ into subsets $A_i$, $f(A_i)=0$ for all but finitely many $i$ (say such a functional is *of finite type*).  To prove this, say that a subset $A\subseteq M$ is *null* for $f$ if $f(B)=0$ for all $B\subseteq A$, and say that $A$ is an *atom* for $f$ if $f(A)=1$ and there do not exist disjoint $B,C\subseteq A$ such that $f(B)=f(C)=1$.

I first claim that if $A$ is an atom for $f$, then the restriction of $f$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the characteristic function of an ultrafilter.  First, if $B\subseteq C\subseteq A$ and $f(B)=1$, then $f(C\setminus B)$ must be $0$ (since $B$ and $C\setminus B$ are disjoint subsets of $A$) so $f(C)=1$ as well.  Second, if $f(B)=f(C)=1$ then $f$ sends at most one of the disjoint sets $B\setminus C, C\setminus B,$ and $B\cap C$ to $1$, and the only option compatible with $f(B)=f(C)=1$ is that $f(B\cap C)=1$.  Finally, since $f(A)=1$, for any $B\subseteq A$ exactly one of $f(B)=1$ or $f(A\setminus B)=1$ is true.

Now I claim that if $f$ is any functional of finite type, there is a finite partition of $M$ into sets which are each either null or an atom for $f$.  It then follows easily that $f$ is the sum of the $\phi_U$'s for the ultrafilters on each of the atoms.

So, suppose that there does not exist any finite partition of $M$ into sets which are either null or an atom for $f$; we will show that $f$ is not of finite type.  First suppose that for any non-null $A\subseteq M$, there exists $B\subseteq A$ that is an atom.  We can then construct a sequence of infinitely many disjoint atoms: first, since $M$ is not null, there exists an atom $A_1$.  Then $M\setminus A_1$ cannot be null (or else $A_1,M\setminus A_1$ would be the desired partition) so it contains an atom $A_2$.  Then similarly $M\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)$ cannot be null so it contains an atom $A_3$, and so on.  In the end we get infinitely many disjoint atoms $A_n$ for $f$, showing that $f$ is not of finite type.

So we may assume there exists a non-null $A\subseteq M$ which contains no atom.  Since $A$ is not null we can take $B_0\subseteq A$ such that $f(B_0)=1$.  Since $B_0$ is not an atom we can find disjoint $A_1,B_1\subseteq B_0$ such that $f(A_1)=f(B_1)=1$.  Since $B_1$ is not an atom we can find disjoint $A_2,B_2\subseteq B_1$ such that $f(A_2)=f(B_2)=1$.  Continuing this way, we again get an infinite collection of disjoint sets $A_n$ such that $f(A_n)=1$ for all $n$, showing $f$ is not of finite type.

---

As far as I know there does not exist any nice description for $\mathcal{P}(M)^*$ when $M$ is infinite, or any basis for it that can reasonably be called "explicit" or "canonical".  (One precise way you might say there is no "canonical" basis is that there is no basis that is fixed by every permutation of $M$.  I don't know whether this is actually true.)

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot for the answer and all the interesting additional information!